# Do we have a canonical answer for "Why doesn't b=a; f[a_]:=b; f[1] return 1"?

Tags: discussion

There exist many related posts, but has it ever been explained in a clear and detailed enough way?

Notice a variant of the question in title is

> Why doesn't
>
> ```
> lst = {a, b, c};
> Thread[Unevaluated@f[lst]]
> ```
>
> return
>
> ```
> {f[a], f[b], f[c]}
> ```
>
> ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88964/discussion-on-question-by-xzczd-do-we-have-a-canonical-answer-for-why-doesnt-b).

Comment: To the downvoter, I am interested in what's wrong with my question, would you please elaborate. I'm not trying to complain here, I just want improve my question if possible.

Answer (score -1):

ANSWERING THE QUESTION IN THE TITLE:

I'm not sure exactly what you don't understand about this, but I can take you through this step by step.

`b = a` is a symbol assignment. It tells Mathematica "from now on, replace `b` with `a`."

Next, `f[a_] := b` defines a replacement rule. The `a_` is a named pattern, and it is unrelated to the symbol `a` mentioned in the first line. This rule is exactly the same as the rule `f[x_] := b` -- the rule doesn't care what you name the pattern. It tells Mathematica to "replace every expression with `f` as the head and one argument with `b`".

Finally, `f[1]` is evaluated. The second rule tells Mathematica to replace this with `b`. Then the first rule tells Mathematica to replace this with `a`.

I'm not sure what exactly is confusing about this. It's important to understand that Mathematica is a *pattern-replacement machine*.

ANSWERING THE SECOND QUESTION:

`Unevaluated@f[lst]` tells Mathematica not to evaluate "`lst`", so, as far as `Thread` is concerned, `lst` is just an undefined symbol.

So, `Thread[Unevaluated@f[lst]]` is evaluated the same way as `Thread[f[X]]` where `X` is just an undefined symbol, which would give `f[X]`.

So,`Thread[Unevaluated@f[lst]]` gives `f[lst]`.

Next, `f[lst]` is evaluated, it gives `f[{a,b,c}]`

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't what I'm asking for. Notice the underlying issue of the 2 specific questions is the same, and what I'm looking for is an existing answer that answers both question in a clear and detailed enough way. (If we don't have an ready-made one, I'd like to see somebody create one in the main site rather than here, of course. )

Comment: …Please notice here is [Meta Mathematica Stack Exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: I'm still not sure what is the underlying question. How are these two related? What output would you expect?

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that. My bad.

Comment: You may want to read the discussion in the chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88964/discussion-on-question-by-xzczd-do-we-have-a-canonical-answer-for-why-doesnt-b